# Fixed Position Rectangles in SSRS 2016

Tags: ssrs-2016

I have a report that is designed to give us a visual representation of available kennel space in our facility. The floorplan image is defined as the background image on a rectangle. Each of the kennel areas are contained in a rectangle on top of the rectangle with the floorplan. I'm happy to share the rdl file if there is a way to upload it to this post (it is 9,559 lines of XML so not practical to copy the code in the post).

When I started into this particular project, I searched for a way to preserve position of each of the report items and the rectangle method came back as the only way to guarantee position at the time the report is generated. I have spent a considerable amount of time making sure each rectangle is positioned precisely where it needs to be on the page. In the designer, when I preview the report, it is as perfect as I can get (note that the image shows the dog lost & found area not lining up as I haven't completed that area just yet). I'm able to zoom in and out in preview and everything stays put exactly where I expect to see it.

[image: Image from Designer]

On Friday, I decided to publish what I had completed to the server and I'm greatly disappointed at how it looks on the server. I'm at a loss to know how to correct it and can't find anything other than using the rectangles as I have already done. Here is the output on the server:

[image: Image from Server]

I even tried it in Internet Explorer and Edge to make sure it wasn't an issue with Chrome. I have not tried Firefox since I don't have it loaded and don't have a need (or desire) to load it. Any ideas as to how to fix this issue are appreciated!

Comment: This is just guessing but have you tried to put the background image in a rectangle of its own (and remove it from the background). That way it should get treated the same way as the other rectangles and note scaled differently because of the device info differences.

Comment: Hi Alan, sorry, I should have clarified. I do have the background image in a rectangle of its own already and everything is added on top of that.

Comment: No problem Jim. The only other things I would check are that the consume container whitespace property is set on in the report properties and that all images (I guess just the one) are the exact size they need to be (they match the exact size of the containing rectangle). I'm not sure what else to suggest. I'm happy to test it on my setup in case that gives any more clues as long as the dataset is provided in the rdl

Comment: I would be happy to send the rdl and a dataset (I'm assuming the dataset is contained in the rdl.data file). How would I upload it to get it to you? I can also send the original .png image if that helps.

Comment: As long as the data is not pulled from an external source you'll be ok. If it is then then you would have to recreate it in your dataset query. Then zip the entire solution (assuming Visual Studio) or just the RDL (if using Report Builder) and save to to something like a OneDrive account or other file sharing site.

Comment: Didn't think about OneDrive... Here is a link to the .zip file: https://dumbfriendsleague-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/jpowers_ddfl_org/EmhPdmX8kuZJizCn8v4Kx7UBxLzN_Yp5-UntOkPVo0Bj3g?e=CFUOBn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174738/discussion-between-alan-schofield-and-jim-powers).

Comment: please join me in the chat room above